# Email 'from address' has a www in it

Tags: email, wp-mail

When sending emails from my WordPress install, my 'from address' includes a *www*.

Currently, it's sending email from *web@www.domain.com* when what I want is *web@domain.com*.

However, if I change the domain name - lets say to *abc.com* - it works properly.

I tried to add some code to my theme's `functions.php` to force a rewrite of the domain name, but I'm still getting the same result.

Has anyone experienced something like this?

Answer (score 4):

You can change the email address with the [`wp_mail_from`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_mail_from/) filter:

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail_from', function() { return 'web@example.com'; } );
```

Comment: I did this before in my function, but still not working. This problem only appeared for the specific domain. Like I said before, if use domain.com email address always using www and the other hand if I changed used abc.com or other domain name from functions will works well.

Comment: There's something else causing the email address to change, then. If the headers are already set, `wp_mail` will use them; if not, then it uses `wordpress@$sitename` after it strips 'www.' from `$sitename`. Check your installed plugins to see if any of them are defining their own `wp_mail` function that doesn't use the same core filters to modify the address.

Comment: Had to disabled plugins, and also switch back onto default theme still no luck. This only happened for a one domain (in my example if used domain.com). Is it possible cause by the server configuration or NS pointing? My server running under Linux Ubuntu VPS

Comment: Since WordPress doesn't send email from 'web@www.domain.com' on its own, then I'm going to guess it's outside of the WP install that this is happening.

Comment: Mmmm...do you mean is cause by server or NS or something else. Ok, I think I need to go to discuss with hosting guy. Thanks for the comment